# htaccess rewrite domain to subfolder including subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My folder structure is:

```
- olddomain.com
- olddomain.com/folderA
- olddomain.com/folderA/subfolderA
- olddomain.com/folderB
```

I have a new domain name, and I want to point it to folderA.
So far so good, in the browser "**newdomain.com**" takes me to "**olddomain.com/folderA**" without showing it in the URL (*user always sees newdomain.com)*, which is what I want.

But in the browser "**newdomain.com/subfolderA/**" takes me to a 404 page, instead to "**olddomain.com/folderA/subfolderA/**".
Any ideas how to include in the rewrite all subfolders and keep the url structure?

This is my .htaccess code so far.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?newdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folderA/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folderA/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?newdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folderA/index.html [L]
```

Comment: What you have looks like it should already "work", providing you don't have another `/subfolderA` directory in the document root. (Although strictly speaking, you are missing the `L` flag on the first `RewriteRule` directive.) What are you expecting to be served when requesting `/subfolderA/` (ie. `/folderA/subfolderA/`)? Do you have a `DirectoryIndex` document in that directory? Is the rewrite being triggered? Is the 404 triggered after the rewrite?

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite. This seems to work if I go to "newdomain.com/subfolderA/subfolderA" (even though there is really no "subfolderA" within "subfolderA"). I'll keep trying!

Comment: To clarify, both `newdomain.com` and `olddomain.com` point to the same directory? Why not change the `DocumentRoot` of `newdomain.com` and have it point directly to `/folderA/` (and then do away with your `.htaccess` file altogether)?

Comment: They do not point to the same directory, no :( still want to keep `olddomain.com`  pointing to the same folder, and `newdomain.com` only to the folderA. Thanks for trying @MrWhite! (cannot mark a comment as correct answer though!)

Comment: "and `newdomain.com` only to the folderA" - yes, that's what the mod_rewrite directives are doing in `.htaccess`, but which folder do the domains actually resolve it? i.e. without any `.htaccess` file, to which folder do the two domains point to?

Comment: Without `.htaccess file`, both domains point to root folder. With `.htaccess`, `olddomain.com` points to root folder, and `newdomain.com` points to `newdomain.com/folderA/folderA`. Yes, `folderA` is repeated for some reason, thats why when I go to `newdomain.com/folderA/file.php` it gives a 404 error, but when I go to `newdomain.com/folderA/folderA/file.php` it works fine. 
Maybe I'm missing some fine within  `folderA`? Should any  `.htaccess`  file be there, to indicate that is the root folder for  `newdomain.com` or something?